How to debug "Steam timeout" & "upstream request timeout" in GKE
I am experiencing a strange behavior in my application. When I try to access my app url when runs in GKE. I am getting "upstream request timeout" or "Steam timeout" for the first time. When I refresh the page I am could see the expected response. After some time, I am getting "upstream request timeout" or "Steam timeout". When I access the same url from inside the pod, I am getting expected response. Can you help me on how to debug this issue.

Try below troubleshooting steps which will help you to resolve your issue:

As per this Official Document upstream request timeout, a firewall rule may be missing to allow traffic from the proxy-only subnet to the pods. As per this note section, if this firewall rule is not created automatically you need to manually add the firewall rule.

Besides a firewall rule to allow traffic from the health check probes, a firewall rule must be  configured to allow traffic from the proxy-only subnet to the target port of the Service.
So for example. If your proxy-only subnet is 10.129.0.0/23, and your pods listen to 9376, you need to create a rule to allow traffic from the subnet to TCP:9376.

After adding the above firewall rule check for missing and add the missing firewall rule for proxy-only subnet. This document  Configure the proxy-only subnet has more details.

Check logs for any errors or response codes.

Check the logs and usage of CPU and memory resources running out, if they have reached the limit, increase to the required limits respectively.


